# Theme of Typography not working properly on Material-UI (React)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, themes

I have a recurrent problem in more than one project on Material-UI's Theme that I was ignoring but now its starting to scale. I started a simple NextJs project with `npx create-next-app@latest --tailwind` for demonstration for this question.

I have the following `mui/theme.js` file that sets a palette and a font-family for Typography:

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#020203',
        },
        secondary: {
            main: '#60606e',
        },
    },
    typography: {
        fontFamily: [
            'Montserrat',
            'sans-serif',
        ].join(','),
      },
    
});

export default theme;
```

And I apply this theme on my `layout.js` using Material-UI's Theme Provider (the imports are ok) like this:

```
'use client'
import './globals.css'
import { Montserrat } from 'next/font/google';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import theme from '../../mui/theme';
import { AppBar, Box, Button, Toolbar, Typography } from '@mui/material';


const montserrat = Montserrat({ subsets: ['latin'], weight: ['100', '300', '400', '500', '700'] })

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={montserrat.className}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
        <CssBaseline />
        <div>
        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <AppBar position="static">
              <Toolbar>
                <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                  eStore
                </Typography>
                <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
              </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
          </Box>
        </div>

          {children}
      </ThemeProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

**I've already confirmed the imports works because of the palette and all the other properties I use from the themes in my other projects.**

So, I did this home page to try it out:

```
'use client'
import { Button, Typography } from '@mui/material'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      
      <div class="mt-5">
        Hello in Montserrat from div
      </div>

      <Typography>
        Hello NOT in Montserrat from Typography
      </Typography>

      <Button variant="outlined">
        Hello NOT in Montserrat from Button
      </Button>

    </div>
    )
}
```

[homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UPt1.png)
(In the image, we can also see that the Montserrat font family is applied through "MuiTypography-root")

I can see that the Montserrat from the NextJs I defined in the body of the project works because of the div. But the components from Material-UI do not have the font family I defined, nor from the theme or from the body.

So, finally, **what is the best approach to globally change Material-UI's font family?**

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of the font in the MUI Theme is okay, you just need also to import the font in your `index.css` file of the app, there are several different ways to be done, but in my opinion this is the easiest.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
```

You can use google fonts to configure, add/remove some of the different variations of the font.
Link to your font [here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat?preview.text=Hello%20world&preview.text_type=custom).